# Bootstrap columns just stack vertically

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to make some columns here:

```
<div class="container-fluid" id="content">
  <div class="row" id="slideshow">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <h1 id="greeting">Welcome to Website.com!</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 centerButton" id="button1">
      button 1
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 centerButton" id="button2">
      button 2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 centerButton" id="button3">
      button 3
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 centerButton" id="button4">
      button 4
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want a large rectangular set of buttons 4 buttons (2x2), but all 4 divs are stacked. I've even tried it without the "col-xs-12" class added. I installed the correct version of bootstrap with bower, and other bootstrap classes seem to function well enough. I've also tried re arranging the scope of the container a lot to include the welcome message and slideshow bit and excluding it to make a simple and pure block of columns. Even cloumns like "col-sm-1" stack vertically. I know there are similar questions asked, but I have tried the solutions to all of them, and nothing is working for me.

Comment: Make sure you import jQuery before importing the Bootstrap JS. Also, make sure that you are not getting any console errors related to your imports.

It is also good practice to define the columns for lg, md, and sm for each column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap is functioning properly, but your screen size is likely at the `xs` level, meaning `col-xs-12` renders the columns as full-width sections. Try changing each `col-xs-12 col-sm-6` to just `col-xs-6`:

```
<div class="container-fluid" id="content">
  <div class="row" id="slideshow">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <h1 id="greeting">Welcome to Website.com!</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 centerButton" id="button1">
      button 1
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 centerButton" id="button2">
      button 2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 centerButton" id="button3">
      button 3
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 centerButton" id="button4">
      button 4
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

That should have each button shown in a half-width section. See this [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/rm1JhQeWps) for an example.

With buttons it would look similar to this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6 centerButton form-group" id="button1">
    <button class="btn btn-default btn-block">1</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 centerButton form-group" id="button2">
    <button class="btn btn-default btn-block">2</button>
  </div>
   <div class="col-xs-6 centerButton form-group" id="button3">
    <button class="btn btn-default btn-block">3</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 centerButton form-group" id="button4">
    <button class="btn btn-default btn-block">4</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Bootply 2](http://www.bootply.com/uo9GRPjtjn)